# PHP Date with Setlocale

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to find the day in the week (i have the date).

In my json archive, the date returns: DD/MM/YYYY (15/07/2014), and now i have to find which the day is in the week, AND return in my language (pt-br).

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

echo date("l", '15/07/2014');
```

I've tried some things, but nothing going well :'(

Answer (score 0):

To find out a day of week:

```
$dw = date( "w", $timestamp);
```

Where $dw will be 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday) as you can see here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: It's okay, but, today is Thursday ("Quinta" in my country, case 4), and the script returns case 3 (In my country Quarta, yesterday).